# using data attribute

Tags: css

hi i am making a drum kit with vanila js
I want to make the border-color change to the color corresponding to the keyboard when I press the keyboard.
i want to use data-* attribute in css

Comment: You probably want [`attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr). Then you can update the attribute with JS as needed.

Comment: You can also use css variables and then [use JS to update the variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript) that is referenced in the css.